# android emulator on eclipse won't open

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation

I've gotten it to work before but now the android emulator on eclipse refuses to open. No new window, nothing. Most of the time the console says nothing when I tell it to launch, other times it says "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured." but if I try again after waiting a bit it goes away then it says Launching.... and does nothing.

I try to delete the avds and it says they are currently running in emulators and cannot be deleted even though there are no windows open. I tried re-installing the (1.6) SDK and that didn't work.

Oh and I'm using Ubuntu

Edit The console is finally working, after complaining about adb, I ran it again and I got

"Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device "XXX" and then nothing

then I tried to launch a different project with the same emulator and got:

Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD "XXX" is not available. Launching new emulator.
Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device "XXX"

Comment: inside one of the sdk directories, I think it is tools you will find the adb command.  Try running adb devices and see if you see the emulator or any attached devices.

Answer (score 0):

Run `adb kill-server` and then `sudo adb start-server`  and then `adb devices` and see if you see the emulator. Sometimes the emulator is running but it hides somewhere.  Also trying running the app in debug mode. Also the emulator can be just damn slow sometimes.  adb is a command located in the sdk tools directory I think.  Add it to your path and it will save you a lot of time. You can also do install and uninstall of your apps using command. Then tell us what you see.

Comment: where do I type those in, I'm using Ubuntu and terminal didn't recognize it

Comment: OK I found out how to do kill server in Ubuntu and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue and I solved it by running the emulator from the command line. Go to the tools folder in the SDK package and start the emulator from there, use the name of the emulator you setup in Eclipse (in Virtual Device Manager):

```
./emulator -avd [the name]
```

The GUI should either come up (the GUI comes up fairly quick but will "idle" quite a bit) or you'll probably get an error on the command line. For me it was a missing library, namely libGL.so. Install a lib with apt-get containing libGL and retry.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
./emulator -avd [the name]
```

I did some googling and I'm not the only one, and of course those libs are missing in a 64 bit environment. [Here's another one with the same problem](http://technophilism.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/android-sdk-gpu-accelerated/).

Hope it helps!